# Nginx index module not point to index.php

Tags: php, nginx, subdomain

My problem is access main site: `example.com` not point to `index.php`, i have to manually enter full url `example.com/index.php`.

Subdomain `sub01.example.com` working well, automatic point to index.php.

I've 3 site as bellow, please help to check

main site: example.com

subdomain: sub01.example.com, sub02.example.com

and this is my configure:

```
    server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;

    # root directive should be global
    root   /var/www/example.com/;
    index  index.php;

    access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name sub01.example.com www.sub01.example.com;

    # root directive should be global
    root   /var/www/sub01.example.com/;
    index  index.php;

    access_log /var/www/sub01.example.com/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/sub01.example.com/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name sub02.example.com www.sub02.example.com;

    # root directive should be global
    root   /var/www/sub02.example.com/;
    index  index.php;

    access_log /var/www/sub02.example.com/logs/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/www/sub02.example.com/logs/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index   index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: take a look into nginx logs

Comment: Dear @RomaRush  both access, error log are empty.

Comment: Oh, i see example.com does not pointed to hosting ip, subdomain does although i did point to hosting on cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry.

## This configuration was fine.

Error come from cloudflare DNS pointer config.